# Python confusion with returning variables

Tags: python, function, parameters, return

There's something I don't understand here when it comes to returning variables.  For the sake of simplicity, I wrote a really basic thing to sum up the problem I'm having:

```
def apples():
    dingo = 2
    return dingo

def bananas(dingo):
    print(dingo)

def main():
    apples()
    bananas(dingo)

main()
```

So I create 'dingo' in the 'apples' function.  I return it.  I use it as a parameter in 'bananas'.  I call them both in main, so why do I get the error that 'dingo' is undefined?  Also, something I'm unable to do is put `dingo = apples()` inside the bananas function.  I can't unpack it within the bananas function because I want to call them both in main individually.  Is there any way to get around this without unpacking?

Comment: apples() is returning something. But you are not assigning the returned value to something. `dingo = apples()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that error because you didn't assign the return value of `apples()` to anything, especially not a variable named `dingo` in the scope of `main()`. This would work:

```
def apples():
    dingo = 2
    return dingo

def bananas(dingo):
    print(dingo)

def main():
    result = apples()
    bananas(result)

main()
```

Notice how I named the variable `result` - it doesn't have to be named the same as the argument of the `bananas()` function - it just has to be passed in with the name you assigned it to.

`def bananas(dingo)` basically means: Create a function called `bananas` that takes exactly one argument. Inside `bananas()`, refer to that argument as `dingo`.

So whatever that argument is called in the scope where you call `bananas()` is irrelevant.

Same for apples: You create a variable `dingo`, assign it the value `2` and return it - what's actually returned is just the value (`2`), it's up to you to assign that result to variable that may or may not be called the same.

Answer (score 0):

what you've returned should be assigned to some variable, otherwise the return value gonna be lost.

I'm curious didn't you get `NameError: global name 'dingo' is not defined` with your sample code?

```
In [38]: def apples():
    ...:     dingo = 2
    ...:     return dingo
    ...: 
    ...: def bananas(dingo):
    ...:     print(dingo)
    ...: 
    ...: def main():
    ...:     dingo=apples()
    ...:     bananas(dingo)
    ...: 
    ...: main()
2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def apples():
    dingo = 2
    return dingo

def bananas(dingo):
    print(dingo)

def main():
    apples()
    bananas(dingo)

main()
```

The variable `dingo` is a local variable for the function definition `apples()` and its scope(lifetime) ends as soon as the function call is done with.That means the variable name `dingo` doesn't hold any meaning as soon as the function is over.

`apples()` will return `dingo`no doubt but the function `bananas()` knows nothing about dingo and neither does `main()` since `dingo` is a local variable and confined to `apples()`

For example:

```
def ret_val():
    var=5
    return var
main()
    x=ret_val
    print x
Output:
5
```

the return statement only returns the value in the variable and not the variable by name.
so you should replace code by the following:

```
def apples():
    dingo = 2
    return dingo

def bananas(dingo):
    print(dingo)

def main():
    x=apples()#here x will store the value of dingo i.e 2
    bananas(x)#the value of x will be passed

main()
```

Whenever you return something the return statement terminates the function irrespective of the place where it is in the code of the function(i.e. the last statement or in the middle)

```
def check(x):
   if (x % 2==0):
      return "even"
   return "odd"
```

Once the control goes to return statement then the function ends and the other return statement is not executed.Hence the return is like a break statement for functions which also gives back a value to the calling function.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, there is nothing special about variables names between scopes:

The code given in the accepted answer is the same as this:

```
def apples():
    dingo = 2
    return dingo

def bananas(another_name):
    print(another_name)

def main():
    result = apples()
    bananas(result)

main()
```

What you call the parameter to `bananas` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

In your `main` function definition change the code to look like the following

```
def main():  
   bananas(apples())
```

This way you avoid any temporary assignment of the return values